# React - function not executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know why this is not working. When I run `removeFromCart`, it works but it doesn't work in `updateCount` . Please help me fix this.

```js
    updateCount = (id,increment) => {
        const cartItems = this.state.cart;
        if((this.findItem(cartItems, id).count == 1 && increment < 0))
            this.removeFromCart(id);
        else{
            this.findItem(cartItems, id).count += increment;
        }

        this.setState({
            cart: cartItems
        });
    }

    removeFromCart = id=>{
        const cartItems = this.state.cart.filter(el=> el.id !== id);
        this.setState({
            cart: cartItems
        });
    }

    findItem = (arr,id)=> {
        return arr.find(e=> e.id === id);
    }
```

You can find the full source on [Github](https://github.com/sauravk7077/webstore)

Comment: What's the error that you're seeing?

Comment: I am not getting any error.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "it" is that is or isn't working? What does `findItem` do? Looks like you is mutating *some* object.

Comment: 'it' is `removeFromCart`. `findItem` helps to get the object whose id is equal to `id`.

Comment: I have added github repo's link there..

Comment: Can you update your question to include all relevant code? It's not our responsibility to dig through your entire codebase. Whatever `findItem` is it is possibly returning false for this condition: `this.findItem(cartItems, id).count == 1` or `increment` is zero or greater, and thus taking the other logic branch and getting mutated. `this.findItem(cartItems, id).count += increment;` is also a state mutation, btw.

Comment: Please update the locale file of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a bit of time poring over your code, not much was obviously wrong (other than state mutations), eventually I just cloned your repo into a codesandbox and debugged.

## Issue

The issue is the state update from `updateCount` and another from `removeFromCart`. The condition `this.findItem(cartItems, id).count == 1 && increment < 0` is true and `this.removeFromCart` is called, the cart item is found and a state update it enqueued. Execution returns to `updateCount` and a second state update is enqueued. The second update overwrites the first with the `cartItems` (state) enclosed in function scope.

```
updateCount = (id, increment) => {
  const cartItems = this.state.cart;
  if (this.findItem(cartItems, id).count == 1 && increment < 0)
    this.removeFromCart(id);
  else {
    this.findItem(cartItems, id).count += increment;
  }
  this.setState({
    cart: cartItems // <-- State update #2
  });
};

removeFromCart = (id) => {
  const cartItems = this.state.cart.filter((el) => el.id !== id);
  this.setState({
    cart: cartItems // <-- State update #1
  });
};
```

## Solution

When removing an item from the cart only enqueue a single state update. Tuck the second update into the logic branch that is updating it.

```
updateCount = (id, increment) => {
  const cartItems = this.state.cart;
  if (this.findItem(cartItems, id).count == 1 && increment < 0)
    this.removeFromCart(id);
  else {
    this.findItem(cartItems, id).count += increment;
    this.setState({
      cart: cartItems
    });
  }
};
```

At this point your code appears to function correctly, but I should note that `this.findItem(cartItems, id).count += increment;` is technically a state mutation. It's obscured by the fact that a line later you at least copy into a new state object. You should ***always*** avoid state mutations. I suggest the following edit to map to a new cart array when updating item counts. Also use `===` instead of `==` for equality comparisons unless you have a good reason to.

```
updateCount = (id, increment) => {
  const cartItems = this.state.cart;
  if (this.findItem(cartItems, id).count === 1 && increment < 0)
    this.removeFromCart(id);
  else {
    this.setState({
      cart: cartItems.map((item) =>
        item.id === id
          ? {
              ...item,
              count: item.count + increment
            }
          : item
      )
    });
  }
};
```

[image: Edit react-function-not-executing]